# What's the Drupal equivalent of Sentry?

Tags: 7

I use [getsentry](http://getsentry.com)  for my Django deployments. It's awesome for automatically emailing me when a user experiences a bug in the code, and sending me the stack trace for any exceptions that occur.

Does Drupal have anything equivalent? I've seen the [Drupal Sentry plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/sentry_client) but it doesn't look like it's under active development.

What's the best way of monitoring bugs in production for Drupal?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/raven looks like a good option now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/php/drupal).

> **Database performance**
>
> Viewing slow SQL queries is a breeze. Most Drupal sites rely heavily
>   on Views and CCK which can generate non-optimal SQL queries. New Relic
>   allows you to quickly pinpoint these types of queries.
>
> **Modules Monitoring**
>
> You can identify which modules are slowest by call count or by slowest
>   call time. This may help you identify which modules may be running
>   rogue within your application.
>
> **Apdex**
>
> New Relic uses Apdex scoring to help you evaluate how well your Drupal
>   application is performing for your end-users according to an
>   industry-standard measurement. This helps you provide better data as
>   well as have a clearer understanding of what percentage of your users
>   are frustrated or satisfied. Apdex scoring also provides more specific
>   context than a general “the site is slow” complaint that may not even
>   get to you until hours after the incident. Apdex also gives you a more
>   objective way to measure your end-users’ experience with your
>   performance improvements.
>
> **Function Performance**
>
> Using Web Transaction Traces, you can see which functions are the
>   slowest in your application. You can use this to identify slow
>   functions in custom modules you have written, or to track delays in
>   your application caused by community module functions that do things
>   like authenticate with third-party systems.
>
> **Front-end performance**
>
> All that wonderful flexibility within blocks, views, and panels can
>   sometimes result in complex page renderings that need to be processed
>   by the browsers of your end-users. New Relic’s Real User Monitoring
>   (RUM) will actually gather timing information and show you which
>   hotspots in DOM rendering time may be causing your page to take
>   several seconds to load.

Comment: +1 for New Relic. It is very advanced APM for Drupal. Yes the paid account will give you fidelity down to the function call creating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/product/) has a similar tool to New Relic that allows introspection of a running php application with detailed reports and exceptions.